# Combine multiple ganttbars for the same title

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt, gantt

In the MWE below

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
  vgrid,
  hgrid,
  bar/.append style={fill=red!50},
  group/.append style={draw=black, fill=green!50},
  milestone/.append style={fill=orange, rounded corners=3pt}
  ]{1}{12}
  \gantttitle{Project}{12} \\
  \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{3} \\
  \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=yellow} ]{Task 1}{2}{8} \\
  \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=green} ]{Task 1}{5}{7}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

is there a way to combine the mutiple gantt bars under the same title "Task 1"?

Ideally something like this (or preferably with reduced bar height)

[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place several `\ganttbar`s into one row and then scale the height and shift them accordingly. Place the label only into the first bar.

In order to get proper vertical alignment, it is advisable to adjust both `bar height` as well as `bar top shift`. In the following example, I used `bar height=.2` and `bar top shift=.4`. I added two normal bars to show the output in comparison:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
      vgrid,
      hgrid,
      bar/.append style={fill=red!50},
  ]{1}{12}
  \gantttitle{Project}{12} \\
  \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=yellow}]{Task 2}{2}{8} \\
  \ganttbar[bar height=.2, bar top shift=.4, bar/.append style={yshift=.2cm}]{Task 1}{1}{3} 
  \ganttbar[bar height=.2, bar top shift=.4, bar/.append style={fill=yellow}]{}{2}{8} 
  \ganttbar[bar height=.2, bar top shift=.4, bar/.append style={fill=green, yshift=-.2cm}]{}{5}{7} \\
  \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=yellow}]{Task 2}{2}{8} 
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an easy solution, you can simply leave the labels of the first two bars and only keep that in the middle as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
  vgrid,
  hgrid,
  bar/.append style={fill=red!50},
  group/.append style={draw=black, fill=green!50},
  milestone/.append style={fill=orange, rounded corners=3pt}
  ]{1}{12}
  \gantttitle{Project}{12} \\
  \ganttbar{}{1}{3} \\
  \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=yellow} ]{Task 1}{2}{8} \\
  \ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=green} ]{}{5}{7}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

And this is how the result looks like:
[image]